# Undo "Always activate plugins for this site" in firefox

Tags: firefox

I accidentally always-activated a plugin for a site I didn't mean to. How do I undo it?
[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2012-12-20-12-55-17-d56e89.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Permissions Manager](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/permissions-manager-give-ability-store-passwords-set-cookies-more) to customize permissions for individual sites or set the default permissions for all sites.

> To open the Permissions Manager, just type the words about:permissions
>   into the location bar as if it were a website and hit Enter. The
>   current tab will be replaced by the Permissions Manager.
>
> On the left hand side you'll see a search bar with a list of all the
>   websites you've been to below it. The right hand side lists the
>   various website permissions that Firefox stores.
>
> To work with a single website you have to select it from the list on
>   the left side. You can quickly narrow down that long list by typing
>   part of the site's address in the search box. Once you've selected a
>   site, you can manage its permissions with the settings on the right.

Specifically in your case, search for the site you need and check it in the list on the left. Then change the Plugins dropdown back to "Always Ask".

Alternatively you can browse to a website and view the Page Info ([instructions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page)) to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/permissions-manager-give-ability-store-passwords-set-cookies-more
or like this: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page

Comment: It would be better to answer the question, and use the links as a source for your answer, since links die over time. In a couple of years these links might not work any more, but you still want your answer to be valid.